# why i have NULL when saving data in database

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to save with `foreach`

here is what i get from my form

```
  Array
(
    [mulai] => 2016-08-28
    [akhir] => 2016-08-31
    [keterangan] => remarks
    [nip] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1004384
            [1] => 1602744
            [2] => 1501039
        )

)
```

and then here is my saving query.

```
$jumlahrange = $this->db->query("SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'".$mulai."','".$akhir."') AS diff")->row();
        $totaldata = count($nip);
        $skrg = $this->db->query("SELECT GETDATE() tgl")->row();
            for($x = 0;$x<=$totaldata;$x++)
                {
                    for($y=0;$y<$jumlahrange->diff;$y++){
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO attendance 
                            (Nip,AttendanceDate,InTime,OutTime,AttendanceCode,RosterCode,LocationCode,Remarks,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy)
                        values(
                            '".$nip[$x]."',DATEADD(DAY,".$y.",'".$mulai."'),'','','P3','','','".$keterangan."','".$skrg->tgl."','$niplogin','','')
                        ");
                    }
            }
```

i have no problem with my `save` but i have empty field like this in my table. In row `10,11,12` . That row should not exist right?.

I using SqlServer 2008 and Codeigniter . I know i can use `insert_batch`, but i want use this way.

[image]

Comment: Try using foreach loop instead of for and check

Answer (score 1):

in your line `for($x = 0;$x<=$totaldata;$x++)` i'm pretty sure you wanted to write `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 1):

To overcome these kind of issues you can use  foreach loop instead

```
    foreach($resourcedata as $value){
          //your code goes here and you will get all array elements sequentially in **$value** variable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is right at your fingertips. $nip[$x] is null. Error log or dump and die on the first loop $nip[$x] and see what it returns. If it is in fact not null, then it might be a data type problem (string vs int).